# How to import data from eXist database to PostgreSQL database?

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, exist-db

Is there any extension/tool/script available to import data from [eXist database](http://exist-db.org/) to [PostgreSQL database](http://www.postgresql.org/) automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the tag description it's pretty clear that you're going to need to use an ETL tool or some custom code. Which is easier depends on the nature of the data and how you want to migrate it.

I'd start by looking at Talend Studio and Pentaho Kettle. See if either of them can meet your needs.

If you can turn the eXist data into structured CSV exports then you can probably just hand-define tables for it in PostgreSQL then [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) the data into it or use [`pgloader`](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader).

If not, then I'd suggest picking up the language you're most familiar with (Python, Java, whatever) and using the eXist data connector for that language along with the PostgreSQL data connector for the language. Write a script that fetches data from eXist and feeds it to PostgreSQL. If using Python I'd use [the Psycopg2 database connector](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html), as it's fast and [supports `COPY`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) for bulk data loading.

Comment: You can also try CloverETL. I've found it simpler to use (especially for ETL beginners) compared to Talend and Kettle.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am now doing research between these three. If the rules of stackoverflow do permit, I am happy to receive more suggestions to this thread.

Comment: @user2569149 Sure, and folks can still post answers even after you accept one too; someone might come along with better suggestions than me after all.

Comment: @CraigRinger how to import large json data in postgresql database? thanks in advance.!!!

Comment: @kiran.ray Post a new question please.